# Use case of Spring AOP

Tags: spring, aop

I've learned Spring AOP and its simple use cases (Logging and Checking execution time of methods). Most of Spring AOP examples on the internet contain the same cases.

I wonder if there are any other use cases of Spring AOP in the real life projects.
Please share some of your experiences and knowledge.

Thank you!

Comment: I was recommended this book on AOP related topics. Do go through the topics listed to understand the advanced usecases . [AspectJ in Action 
Practical Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://www.manning.com/books/aspectj-in-action) by Ramnivas Laddad

Comment: Please note that this type of question is off-topic on StackOverflow, because SO is a Q/A platform, not a discussion forum. Your question would only attract opinionated answers.